Dropdown Lists Emptying When Filling Data in Worksheet
I'm experiencing an issue with my Excel VBA code where dropdown lists become empty as I enter data into my worksheet. I've written a macro to set up the dropdowns based on a separate sheet named listes_déroulantes but after I input data into the table, the dropdown lists in my main worksheet stop showing any values.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
Sub EffacerPageName()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsListes As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    ' Set the active sheet and the "listes_déroulantes" sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wsListes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("listes_déroulantes")
    
    ' Clear contents and formats from row 4 onwards
    ws.Rows("4:" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    ws.Rows("4:" & ws.Rows.Count).ClearFormats
    
    ' Delete all tables in the active sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Add headers if missing
    With ws
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "Mois"
        .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Promo"
        .Cells(3, 3).Value = "Code Analytique"
        .Cells(3, 4).Value = "Projet"
        .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Intervenant"
        .Cells(3, 6).Value = "Nombre d'heures" & Chr(10) & "d'intervention"
        .Cells(3, 7).Value = "Détail_Intervention"
        .Cells(3, 8).Value = "Statut"
        .Cells(3, 9).Value = "TVA"
        .Cells(3, 10).Value = "Taux horaire TTC ou" & Chr(10) & "brut"
        .Cells(3, 11).Value = "Total"
        .Cells(3, 12).Value = "Total-frais"
        .Cells(3, 13).Value = "Détail_Frais"
        .Cells(3, 14).Value = "Total-matériel"
        .Cells(3, 15).Value = "Détail_Matériel"
        
        ' Center headers and apply formatting
        .Range("A3:O3").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("A3:O3").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("A3:O3").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A3:O3").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Range("E3:K3").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
        .Range("L3:M3").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
        .Range("N3:O3").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 224, 242)
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
        .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
    End With
    
    ' Create structured table
    With ws
        Dim tblRange As Range
        Set tblRange = .Range("A3:O3")
        Set tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tblRange, , xlYes)
        tbl.Name = "TableauEntetes"
        tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    End With

    ' Add data validations for drop-down lists
    lastRowPromo = wsListes.Cells(wsListes.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With ws.Range("B4:B" & ws.Rows.Count).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=listes_déroulantes!A2:A" & lastRowPromo
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    ' Repeat for other dropdowns...
End Sub

I have a sheet where I input various data, and I have linked dropdown lists in columns B, C, D, H, and I to specific ranges in the listes_déroulantes sheet.
However, as I start entering data (especially when I scroll down the rows), the dropdown lists in these columns clear out and do not show any options anymore.



You need to make the range constant by adding $ signs
Change
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:="=listes_déroulantes!A2:A" & lastRowPromo

to this
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:="=listes_déroulantes!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowPromo

I have spoken about this in What are Relative, Absolute, and Mixed cell references in Excel
